# Is it possible not to be able to index axis 1 of a 2-D array?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

Take a look at this

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ndmin=2)
print(arr.ndim)
print(arr.shape)
```

output

```
>>>2
>>>(1, 5)
```

It's clear that the number of dimension is 2
but why doesn't it work when I try to index an element in axis 1 i.e second dimension

```
print(arr[1, 0]) # First element in second dimension
```

```
# Traceback
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Answer (score 0):

consider  a different shape

```
arr = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])[:, None]
arr.ndim
2
arr.shape
(5, 1)
print(arr[1, 0])
2
```